# Can the union of a closed and an open set (disjoint and separated) be open?

Tags: general-topology

In a topology on X, let A be a closed set disjoint and separated from an open set B (proper subset of X). Is the union of A and B: open? or closed? or open and closed? or not open nor closed? or it is undecidable? or it depends upon the type of topology? or other?

Comment: What does separated mean?

Comment: The union of an open   set and its complement is an example.

Comment: In the discrete topology, every point is both open and closed, so whatever separated means, the answer is yes.  But this is certainly not possible in every topological space.

Comment: For example $X = \mathbb R, A = [-1,1], B = (2,4), A\cup B$ is neither open nor closed.  But $A \cup A'$ is both open and closed.

Comment: It depends upon the space.

Comment: disjoint: for instance A=[-3,0], B=(0,3]; "separated": for instance A=[-3,0) and B=(0,3]. (Just to explain the terms, not specifically applicable to the original question).

Comment: Bernard, thanks, but an open set and its complement would not be "separated" (see my prior comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I think the definition you are seeking is the following: Two sets of a topological space $X$ are called *separated* if their closures are disjoint.

Note that a set is open if an only if it is disjoint from its boundary and a set is closed if and only if it contains its boundary. Let $X$ be a topological space, $Z\subseteq X$ closed and $U\subseteq X$ open such that $Z$ and $U$ are separated. It follows from this that $T:=U\cup Z$ satisfies $\partial T = \partial Z\cup\partial U$. Now if $Z$ is not open or $U$ is not closed, then $T$ is neither disjoint from its boundary nor does it contain it, so in these cases $T$ is neither closed nor open.

However, if $U$ is also closed then $T$ will clearly be closed and if $Z$ is also open then $T$ will clearly be open since finite unions preserve both properties.